# Can't send mail node mailer

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I am getting Recipient Error: Can't send mail - no recipient defined error while sending an email using npm node mailer. I am consulting the example as in the documentation. consider abc@gmail.com with my real email.

```
var emailAddress = "abc@gmail.com";
mailOptions = {
    from: "Admin <abc@gmail.com>", // sender address
    to: emailAddress, // list of receivers
    subject: "Hello", // Subject line
    text: "hello", // plaintext body
    html: "<b>Hello</b>" // html body
}

smtpTransport = nodeMailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "abc@gmail.com",
        pass: "123"
    }
});

smtpTransport.sendMail(mailJson, function(error, response){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
    }

    // if you don't want to use this transport object anymore, uncomment following line
    smtpTransport.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages
});
```

Comment: Is your email address a string? Right now abc@gmail.com is missing quotation marks

Comment: Also the options you're passing to sendMail isn't mailOptions. Is that a typo?

Comment: @C Blanchard, I am editing my whole question now.

Comment: may be you are right i am handeling this in a function and may be not returning the value to the callee. let me check it with this. Will come back to you :)

Comment: I was not returning the value. It is working now. Thankyou :)

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 1):

The following advise would be useful (for others users):

1. `mailJson` is your configuration called `mailOptions`.
2. Would return in a promise your result, which is so useful when you're sending an email in an async code.

So, your code would be the following:

```
mailOptions = {
    from: "Admin <abc@gmail.com>", // sender address
    to: emailAddress, // list of receivers
    subject: "Hello", // Subject line
    text: "hello", // plaintext body
    html: "<b>Hello</b>" // html body
}

smtpTransport = nodeMailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "abc@gmail.com",
        pass: "123"
    }
});

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
            error ? reject(error) : resolve(info);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If no solution work for you

Go to that link and active less secure than try to send mail
[enter link description here](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)